# Can I compress a folder in Windows which will be compatible in AWS Lambda?

Tags: python, linux, windows, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have a Catboost model that I built and persisted (via pickle) using Python and I am trying to deploy this model using AWS Lambda. I have 2 other Python scripts to go along with my model and lambda_function.py script: functions.py and features.py. The Functions script contains functions for parsing a (JSON) payload, generating predictions, and returning a JSON object. The features script contains lists, dictionaries, etc. to make the parsing as efficient as possible. Altogether these scripts have 3 dependencies: numpy, pandas, and catboost.

In AWS Lambda, each of these dependencies and the model need their own "layers". Luckily, lambda has numpy built-in, so I do not need to create a layer for that. However, for pandas and Catboost I need to generate all of the module's files/directories, compress them, and add them to an S3 bucket so they can be used as layers.

I am having to do this on a Windows machine and my work computers (VDI and EC2) will not allow me to install and run Ubuntu on a Virtual Box.

How can I create a compressed folder in a Windows environment that will cooperate with a (Linux) AWS Lambda function?

Comment: What you are asking can't be done. The Windows versions of those libraries won't run in Lambda. You probably need to spin up a Linux EC2 server temporarily to create the Lambda layers.

Answer (score 1):

This is a perfect use case for docker.  I run MacOS and have the same problem that anything Python dependency that requires native binaries, I can't build them on my Mac and expect them to work in the AWS Linux runtime environment

Amazon has a docker container that matches the lambda runtime environment so you can use that to build your layer.

The docker image you want to use is [lambci/lambda](https://hub.docker.com/r/lambci/lambda/), specially the tags prefixed with `build-python` as they have the various python environment (2.7, 3.6, 3.7).

Assuming you have a `requirements.txt` with your required libraries that you want to pip install into your layer, here is an example docker command to run in the same directory as the `requirements.txt` that will pip install the libraries and build them in the AWS Lambda runtime.

```
docker run --rm -v `pwd`:/var/task:z lambci/lambda:build-python3.6 python3.6 \
    -m pip --isolated install -t python -r requirements.txt
```

Comment: Thanks! I was just about to look into using docker for this today, so I appreciate this answer.

Comment: great, this is definitely the standard approach for how you build lambdas in a dev environment agnostic way